# Xpath retrieve the attribute of the node in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, evaluation

I want to retrieve a field with attributes but that doesn't work.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
    <field name="a" class="b" libelle="zozo"></field>
    <field name="c" class="c" libelle="zaza"></field>
</fields>
```

The Xpath expression :

```
//field[@name[.='a'] and @class[.='b']]
```

The Java code:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String fileName = Main.class.getResource("exemple.xml").getFile();
        Document document = getDocument(fileName);
        System.out.println(evaluateXPath(document, "//field[@name='a' and @class='b']")); //updated with the proposition of @Michael 
        System.out.println(evaluateXPath(document, "//field/@name[.='a']")); //to show you that the parser work a bit
    }


    private static Document getDocument(String fileName) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);
        return doc;
    }

    private static List<String> evaluateXPath(Document document, String xpathExpression){

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            if (nodes != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    if (nodes.item(i).getNodeValue() != null)
                        values.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
                }
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

With this set up I expect to get

```
<field name="a" class="b" libelle="zozo">
```

But i don't get anything.
I tried with online Xpath validators and it worked but not in Java..

I saw that it could come from namespace in xml but there is none in mine.

Thanks for your help

## Solution

As @Alexandra said below, I was using a method that would return null in my case.

In order to retrieve a value from an attribute you have to use :

```
nodes.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("YourAttributeName");
```

Comment: Your code looks fine (though it's a bit convoluted: you could write the predicate as `[@name='a' and @class='b']`). Either there's something wrong with the code you haven't shown us, or you've found a bug: offhand, the first option seems more likely.

Comment: @Michael i tried it and it doesn't change anything

Comment: Please try posting a complete self-contained Java program that demonstrates the effect, to see if other people can reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael, I have updated the post to include more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change XPath evaluation either to

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

or to

```
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

depending on how many nodes are expected to be found.

Comment: I can see in the debugger that I get a null value (either in XPathConstants.NODESET or in XPathConstants.NODE ) no matter if it's a nodelist or not

Comment: Expression `if (nodes.item(i).getNodeValue() != null)` in your code returns false because method getNodeValue() of class org.w3c.Node returns null for Node.ELEMENT_NODE, see documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Comment: Thank's for your answer, i had to add something like 
nodes.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name")) 
to get the result of the attribute "name".
you helped me out !

Comment: For that purpose you could change XPath to `//field[@name='a' and @class='b']/@name`. Than it will return the value of the "name" attribute of the element satisfying given conditions.